# Error When Git Bash Installing React-Scripts "UNKNOWN: unknown error, scandir 'E:\...\node_modules\@babel\.helper-annotate-as-pure.DELETE'"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, node-modules

`UNKNOWN: unknown error, scandir 'E:\Sorted\Capstone\WOO-WOO.net\WOO-WOO.net\project\FrontEnd\frontendapp\node_modules\@babel\.helper-annotate-as-pure.DELETE'`

I got this error and similar ones when running the commands `npm update`, `npm audit fix`, and `npm install react-scripts --save` in Git Bash.

I tried force cleaning the cache and get other errors when using `npm start`.

Comment: Is `E:\` a removable drive ? is it connected when you run `npm update` ?

Comment: @LeGEC Yes E: is a removable drive and I always have it plugged in, I've had some issues with it disconnecting while it's plugged in but I think it was fine while running npm update.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, run

```shell
chkdsk E: /f /x
```

You probably have corruption in removable drive E, specifically in that folder.

This command repairs errors in the drive, forcing it to unmount first if necessary.