# Cannot access lib folder from mri package

Tags: node.js, shopify

I'm trying to run a shopify app [following this](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-node)

but when I run

```
npm run dev
```

I get

```
UNKNOWN: unknown error, scandir 'C:\Users\xxx\       │
│  Documentos\apps\shopify_banner_app\banner-app-tutorial\web\node_modul  │
│  es\mri\lib'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could be a system issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71557765/6110804

But you can try removing whole node_modules and trying install again along with removing npm cache

Comment: Either way try to look for `UNKNOWN: unknown error, scandir` which is system specific issue